# nHibernate .net 4.5 support

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-4.5

Does nHibernate support .net 4.5? Or do I have to use nHibernate against my core classes in a  .net 4.0 project and have my other projects in .net 4.5

Comment: I have to do some other stuff first.  It'll be a while before I get to that point.

Comment: It takes < 10 minutes to write a quick test in a console app to test NH against 4.5.

Comment: I Disagree with Phill on this -- why jeapardize a large/expensive project because a 10 minute console app worked?  (if there are subtle bugs, a quick, 10 minute test might not uncover them)

Answer (score 0):

You will have an issue if you wish to use LocalDB in you .NET Framework 4.5 application. The connnection string that you need to use is pipe one:

> `Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#F365A78E\tsql\query;`

This is because .NHibernate is compiled with .NET 4.0 Framework and not .NET 4.5.

For reference see below line in [NHibernate.csporj](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/NHibernate.csproj) from NHibernate Github repository

> `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Answer (score -2):

Yes, .NET 4.5 is fully compatible with .NET 4.0.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. I just created a .NET 4.5 project, and when I reference Castle.ActiveRecord.dll, which is for .NET 4, it starts generating errors.